# undo action. delay ajax call for set time or until next action

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to setup and undo feature that delays my ajax call a set amount of time and gives the user an opportunity to abort the ajax call before it gets called. I would also like to stop the delay and continue with the most recent ajax call if another action is triggered.

For example,
If i sent an email and I'm given 5 min to undo this action, I can send another email to send the previous email and to give this new email 5 min to undo.

I was wondering how I would be able to do this?

Comment: You use `setTimeout()`. One problem is that the user may navigate away from the page before the 5 minutes is up and the timer will be aborted in that case.

Comment: I understand setTimeout() is to set the delay and clearTimeout() is to cancel the request? is there a function that takes out the delay and automatically sends the request? If so can i call this function at any kind of exiting action?

Comment: I don't recommend that plan. Your user should know exactly what's going on. There's a problem too in that unload events don't always get triggered when you expect them to (at least in some older browsers). It might be better to give your user an opportunity to confirm the action, and if it is not confirmed, don't do it.

Comment: I would like to model the Gmail's undo function to my app. The problem with giving a confirm action is that my users will be processing a lot of request per minute. By creating a confirmation for each request it would delay their productivity a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encapsulate the actions and show use the pending actions which use can commit by clicking a button. This way they can any time remove the pending action.

Another way is to create undo action (like if a block of text is deleted, keep the deleted text with position information) that can be executed later to bring system back to previous state.

But if it is something like email sent or data saved to database things get complicated and queuing up pending changes is a better way.

There is an [undo/redo module](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/undo) for YUI library which you can explore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo-code:

- User clicks to send
- If there is a previous one saved ...

  - clear the timeout away
  - call the send function which will ...

    - retrieve the saved one
    - if it hasn't been erased ...

      - erase the saved one
      - call ajax to send it
- Save the current one away
- set the timeout to call the send function (defined above)

Note that "saving" and "retrieving" is simple here. Store it to the 'savedEmail' variable and get it from there. Erasing means you set the 'savedEmail' variable to null.

Comment: is there a way to check whether there is an ongoing timeout or not? If i previously saved something how do i check whether the timeout has expired already which means that i can disregard sending the saved one since the original ajax call sent it already

Comment: You can't check but it doesn't hurt to clear a timeout that has already occurred. You should erase it after sending so you can't send it again. I added some steps for that.

Comment: since ajax is asyncronous, would there ever occur a situation where ajax sends it and before ajax erases the saved one, the saved one is checked and since its not empty it does another ajax request?